# DevExpress RibbonReportDesigner Command property on SaveButton

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am designing an application using RibbonReportDesigner, which will let the user to create his own report template. That app will be a part of bigger application.
When user will save template I need to obtain result of Command Property (it is set on the button in designer as "SaveFile"). Why do I need this? I want to check if user really saved that template- if yes then i have to save report name to database. One of the problems is that the event of button click is executed before the dialog opening and i don't know how to check result of saving template.
How can I achieve this? I don't see in designer any appropiate events, which could be usefull for my purposes.
Code, which I use to fire event of saving file:

```
private void commandBarItem32_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {           
        var result = commandBarItem32.Command.Equals(DialogResult.OK);
        if (result == true)
        {
            //create object- report name etc. and save it to database
        }
    }
```

The reason I need to save it is that in bigger application there will be combobox with a list of created templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to hook all UI events,
it is much easier to just replace the ReportStorage (list, save, load report layouts)

> ReportStorageExtension.RegisterExtensionGlobal(new MyCustomStorage());

where MyCustomStorage implements all CRUD methods to manage the layouts.

For more details you can follow the [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/10001/Creating-Reports-in-Visual-Studio/Detailed-Guide-to-DevExpress-Reporting/Storing-and-Distributing-Reports/Storing-Report-Layouts-and-Documents/Custom-Report-Storage#WindowsForms)